# Identify New Seller (without buying in recent 3 months)

Tags: google-bigquery

In my SQL - BigQuery, I have a table with 3 columns: Month, Date, ID about records of transactions of users.
[Here is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izfY0.png)
I want to identify which ID is the new seller in each month, the definition of a new seller is the seller without buying the recent 3 months.

I tried to sort row_number the ID order by date, ID. I reckon that the row_number not in (2,3,4) is the new seller. However, ID can skip 1 month and rebuy next month, my code doesn't work with this situation.

Could you please help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  COUNT(1) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id 
    ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(`date`, '2000-01-01', MONTH) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) = 0 AS new_seller
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from  your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Mar-19' month, DATE '2019-03-01' `date`, 1 id UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mar-19', '2019-03-03', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mar-19', '2019-03-04', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apr-19', '2019-04-05', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apr-19', '2019-04-06', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Apr-19', '2019-04-07', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'May-19', '2019-05-03', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'May-19', '2019-05-04', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'May-19', '2019-05-05', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jun-19', '2019-06-06', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jun-19', '2019-06-07', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jun-19', '2019-06-08', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jun-19', '2019-06-09', 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jul-19', '2019-07-05', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jul-19', '2019-07-06', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Jul-19', '2019-07-07', 9 
)
SELECT *, 
  COUNT(1) OVER(
    PARTITION BY id 
    ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(`date`, '2000-01-01', MONTH) 
    RANGE BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) = 0 AS new_seller
FROM `project.dataset.table`
-- ORDER BY `date`
```

with below output

```
Row month   date        id  new_seller   
1   Mar-19  2019-03-01  1   true     
2   Mar-19  2019-03-03  2   true     
3   Mar-19  2019-03-04  3   true     
4   Apr-19  2019-04-05  3   false    
5   Apr-19  2019-04-06  4   true     
6   Apr-19  2019-04-07  5   true     
7   May-19  2019-05-03  3   false    
8   May-19  2019-05-04  6   true     
9   May-19  2019-05-05  5   false    
10  Jun-19  2019-06-06  1   false    
11  Jun-19  2019-06-07  7   true     
12  Jun-19  2019-06-08  8   true     
13  Jun-19  2019-06-09  9   true     
14  Jul-19  2019-07-05  2   false    
15  Jul-19  2019-07-06  5   false    
16  Jul-19  2019-07-07  9   false
```